# Click exact checkboxes just javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox, console

There is a page with checkboxes like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="row_select[]" value="21">
<input type="checkbox" name="row_select[]" value="25">
<input type="checkbox" name="row_select[]" value="28">
```

etc.

I know beforehand which "values" should be checked.
How can I check checkboxes with exact values using javascript?
For example "21" and "28"?

*execution supposed in chrome dev tools console.

**this example ofcourse let us match what we need by using [0] and [2]
but I would like to ask you help me with an array-example:
smth like:

```
if [21,28,etc] then check checkboxes with values 21,28, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [21, 28, etc...];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="row_select[]"][value="'+array[i]+'"]').checked = true;
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[name="row_select[]"][value=21]' is not a valid selector.

may be its required jquery?
whether its possible do the same without jquery?

Comment: Needed doublequotes around the `value=` parameter. I've added them.

Comment: Works perfectly. All the best to you Barmar Thanks!